# Reading user posts

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-stream-story

I am planning to use facebook authentication for my application. I thought of using facebook account creation date to identify fake accounts. After extensive searching I retired without a solution.
So decided to read user posts to check if the user account existed for sometime, but using read_stream I could only get a user's feed, I would like to know by someway can I get only the user's post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ see `statuses` connection.

Answer (score 0):

> Calling the Facebook API is a (relatively) slow operation; especially if you have to call it multiple times. So, when possible, it is a good idea to get the information you need, without making API calls.

You can take a look at http://metadatascience.com/2013/03/11/inferring-facebook-account-creation-date-from-facebook-user-id/. It explains how to figure out the creation date of a Facebook account without having to call the Facebook API, just based on the user’s Facebook UID.